# hangman game that doesn't show any errors, however terminal shows nothing

Tags: python, function

```
import random
from Words import words
import string

def get_valid_word(words):
    word = random.choice(words)
    while '-' or ' ' in word:
        word = random.choice(words)
    return word.upper()


def hangman() -> object:
    word = get_valid_word(words)
    word_letter = set(word)
    alphabet = set(string.ascii_uppercase)
    used_letter = set()

    while len(word) > 0:
        print("You have used these letter", ' '.join(used_letter))
        word_list = [letter if letter in used_letter else '-' for letter in word]
        print("Current word: ", ' '.join(word_list))
        user_letter = input("Guess a letter: ")

        if user_letter in alphabet - used_letter:
            used_letter.add(user_letter)
            if user_letter in word_letter:
                word_letter.remove(user_letter)
        elif user_letter in used_letter:
            print("You have already used this letter: ")
        else:
            print("Invalid input")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hangman()
```

I can't bring code to execute function `hangman()`. Terminal only shows the following output:

```
/Users/nighttwinkle/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python
/Users/nighttwinkle/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Your question is a good start but it needs some improvement. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Your code doesn't work out of the box. The package `Word` is unknown. Please try to replace it in your MWE. It is also totaly unclear which of your lines producing the output you showed us. Are you sure this is the real output?

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems but should work (kind of). Try to run this with an empty or simple Hello-World-Example. I assume you will get the same error. The output you showed us points to something is wrong in your environment not in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the line

```
while '-' or ' ' in word:
```

your syntax is slightly off meaning that this will always evaluate to `True` and thus the code enters an infinite loop at this point

python interprets the above as

```
while ('-') or (' ' in word):
```

an thus the string `-` is one half of the `or` statement and any non empty string will always evaluate to `True`
leaving the `while` condition as:

```
while True or ' ' in words:
```

try this intead:

```
while '-' in word or ' ' in word:
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably entering an infinite loop in function `get_valid_word(words)`.

Try to debug your code and check line `while '-' or ' ' in word:`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer are correct. But I wan't to suggest an improvement of your code. There is a redundant because the line `word = random.choice(words)` appears two times.

You can prevent this when you prevent the `while` loop and replace it with a recursive call of `get_valid_word()`.

```
import random
import string
# from Words import words
words = ['FOOBAR', 'FOO-BAR', 'FOO BAR']

def get_valid_word(words):
    word = random.choice(words)

    if '-' in word or ' ' in word:
        return get_valid_word(words)

    return word.upper()
```